# C++ logger for UWP application

Tags: c++, logging, visual-c++, uwp, c++-cli

I'm working on an UWP application in visual C++ (VS 2017) that will be uploaded to Microsoft Store. I'm looking for a configurable third-party logger that may be used for writing logs to files, automatic rolling etc. Is there an off-the-shelf logging library for visual C++ that is fully compatible with UWP and may provide such features? As far as I checked there are only loggers for UWP available in C# (e.g. Serilog, NLog in version 4.5).

If no, is there a way to integrate one of the above-mentioned C# logging frameworks with visual C++? It may be easily done the other way by using shared Windows Runtime components, but I'm not sure if it's feasible in my case.

Comment: Hi and welcome! stackoverflow is more a place where looking for help if you are stuck while writing/adapting code. Could you please provide more details about "your case" and your search/research efforts, including what you tried? Otherwise nobody will be able to help.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. I guess I just thought it's a right place for a question about libraries. 

Basically I'm working on an UWP application in visual C++ (VS 2017) that will be available on Microsoft Store. I'm looking for a logging library (similar to log4cxx or log4cplus) that will provide me with configurable logger capable of writing logs to files, automatic rolling etc. 

Since Microsoft is very strict about UWP requirements I would like to make sure that such logging framework is fully compatibile with UWP. So far I haven't found any open-source solution for C++, only for C#

Comment: @user3718188 UWP has Logging APIs in [the Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.diagnostics). Please see [Logging](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Logging/cpp) sample for more details.